# Setting parameter for stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have setup a stored procedure that uses one input parameter (`@QuestionID`) to retrieve a single record (record comes from elements of multiple data tables).

Have created a datareader and am populating values on my web page with these values.

What I don't know how to do is to set the value of the input parameter off of someone clicking the link to open the "details" page from a list (on the referring page).

Referring page where someone clicks the details record and the `QuestionID` is set:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Caption="Submitted Questions" AllowSorting="True" 
     CaptionAlign="Left" EmptyDataText="You have not submitted any Questions." PageSize="5"
     AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="QuestionID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="KeyObjective" HeaderText="Key Objective" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmitDate" HeaderText="Submitted Date" ItemStyle-Width="50" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Details" runat="server" Text="View Details" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Submit/Submit_Detail.aspx?Id=" + Eval("QuestionID")  %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Clone" runat="server" Text="Create Clone" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Submit/Submit_Clone.aspx?Id=" + Eval("QuestionID")  %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

DataReader control that is currently hardcoded to `@QuestionID` value of 1, I need to get this to accept the querystring value being sent from the referring page:

```
string sConstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(sConstr);

using (Conn)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("QuestionDetail", Conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt));
    command.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = 1;

    Conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
        txt_author.Text = reader["Author"].ToString();

    reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to read it from the `Request` object assuming it matches the URLs provided within your LinkButtons (i.e. the querystring parameter is "Id") :

```
command.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
```

You would just need to adjust this accordingly if your parameter was something different.

Comment: Have tried to implement this, but the value does not seem to be passed. Very new to ASP.NET and C#.       Entered this: command.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["QuestionID"]);

Comment: The `Request` collection will contain numerous values that were passed in or available during the request. So if you had a querystring parameter that looked like `Page.aspx?id=42`, then `id` would be the key and `42` would be the value. So if you needed to access that in the code-behind, you should be able to use `Request["id"]` to resolve it as seen in the example above. You indicated that your Details link would trigger this and it seems to be in the format "~/Submit/Submit_Clone.aspx?Id={value}", so you would likely use `Request["Id"]` to match this key/value accordingly.

Comment: Got it, should have seen that without help. Thanks a bunch.